# Enumerable Select by Expression Tree

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees, enumerable

I'm studying "Expression Tree" but I'm not managing to perform these expressions:

```
// first case
someList.Select(p => p.SomeProperty);
```

and

```
// second case
someList.Select(p => new OtherClass 
{
    SomeProperty = p.SomeProperty
})
```

To the "first case" I tried do this:

```
var someList = new List<SomeClass>();
someList.Add(new SomeClass { SomeProperty = "Hello" });

var someParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeClass), "p");
var someProperty = Expression.Property(someParam, "SomeProperty");

Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable),
    "Select",
    new Type[]
    {
        typeof(SomeClass),
        typeof(string)
    },
    Expression.Lambda(
        someProperty,
        someParam
    )
).Dump();
```

But I get this error:

*InvalidOperationException: No generic method 'Select' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.*

About the "second case", I don't have ideia how to proceed.

Can anyone guide me here?

Comment: I think you are missing supplying the IEnumerable<SomeClass> parameter that would be between `new Type[]` and `Expression.Lambda` in your `Expression.Call`

Comment: You can't use directly expression trees with `Enumerable.*` methods. You have to `.Compile()` them, or use a `IQueryable<>` and `Queryable.*` methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calm down folks, after some research I found what was missing in my code...

On the fist case:

```
Expression.Call(
    typeof(Enumerable),
    "Select",
    new Type[]
    {
        typeof(SomeClass),
        typeof(string)
    },
    Expression.Constant(someList), // <---------------- HERE IT IS
    Expression.Lambda(
        someProperty,
        someParam
    )
);
```

To the second case, I created the "new" expression through the code below:

```
var bind = Expression.Bind(typeof(OtherClass).GetProperty("SomeProperty"), someProperty);
var otherClassNew = Expression.New(typeof(OtherClass));
var otherClassInit = Expression.MemberInit(otherClassNew, bind);
```

Anyway, Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Some examples of what you could do:

Given

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
var someList = new List<SomeClass>();
someList.Add(new SomeClass { SomeProperty = "Hello" });

var someParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeClass), "p");
var someProperty = Expression.Property(someParam, "SomeProperty");

Expression<Func<SomeClass, string>> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<SomeClass, string>>(someProperty, someParam); // p => p.SomeProperty
```

Using an `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`... Note the `.Compile()`

```
Func<SomeClass, string> compiled = lambda.Compile();
IEnumerable<string> q1 = someList.Select(compiled);
```

You shouldn't **ever** use `AsQueryable()` **but** in unit tests and "experimentation" programs (like this one). Just to make @Peter happy, I'll add another possible condition: if you **really** know what it does (not **think** you know what it does, **really**!), then you can use it. But if it the first time you use it, I still suggest you ask on SO if you are right in using it.

```
IQueryable<SomeClass> queryable = someList.AsQueryable();
```

Directly using the `Queryable.Select()`

```
IQueryable<string> q2 = queryable.Select(lambda);
```

Building a `Select` and using the `CreateQuery` (this is very similar to what internally the `Queryable.Select` does) to "inject" it in the query.

```
MethodInfo select = (from x in typeof(Queryable).GetMethods()
                    where x.Name == "Select" && x.IsGenericMethod
                    let gens = x.GetGenericArguments()
                    where gens.Length == 2
                    let pars = x.GetParameters()
                    where pars.Length == 2 && 
                        pars[0].ParameterType == typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(gens[0]) &&
                        pars[1].ParameterType == typeof(Expression<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(gens))
                    select x).Single().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeClass), typeof(string));

MethodCallExpression select2 = Expression.Call(null, select, Expression.Constant(queryable), lambda);

IQueryProvider provider = queryable.Provider;
IQueryable<string> q3 = provider.CreateQuery<string>(select2);
```

Comment: Why should we "never use AsQueryable() but in unit tests and experimentation programs" ? Given such a strong statement it would be good if you backed it up with a short explanation

Comment: @PeterLillevold Because it doesn't do what 90% of C# programmers think it does. If someone uses it outside of a unit test, 9 times out of 10 he doesn't know what he is doing and is simply throwing things until it compiles.

Comment: @PeterLillevold The right sentence should be "you shouldn't use it unless you know what you are doing", but few will admit that they are throwing things until it compiles, so it is easier to use absolutes... Like "don't use `float` and `double` unless you are a game programmer or are creating a PDF".

Comment: ok, so therefore I think that your statement is *highly* opinionated and does not highlight anything that is relevant to the OP question. Using absolutes will not increase awareness and understanding unless you back it up with good reasoning.

Comment: @PeterLillevold The question wasn't about `AsQueryable()`, and I wanted to make it clear that I don't endorse its use anywhere but in some place. Now... There are probably use cases where you can use `AsQueryable()`, but you must be "this much tall" to be able to recognize them.

Comment: again, back that up with a **why**. Technically, **why** is there risk related to using `AsQueryable()`? I understand that you believe 90% of C# programmers are just monkeys throwing code at the compiler, you are entitled to that opinion. But that opinion is hardly relevant to this question.

Comment: @PeterLillevold There is no *risk*. *risk* is when you deference a potentially null pointer. This is more like "if you want to use it, read what it does, we aren't talking about it"... I'm sure on SO there are questions about what it does. This question isn't about `AsQueryable()`, but just because I used it, someone will copy-paste my code in his code, and use `AsQueryable()`. I used a bad pattern, and I explicitly said that it is a bad pattern, and that it is ok just because I'm using it to show something (the using of `IQueryable<>`), not using it in production read code.

Comment: still not happy :) you haven't explained to the masses of poor C# developers what `AsQueryable()` does that is so evil. Either give a good (short) explanation as to what it does that one should be carefull about, *or* remove the argument completely.

Comment: @PeterLillevold I don't *need* / *have* to explain every opinion I have in every place I use it. If you don't like my opinion, you can confute it, or you can ignore it. For example instead of writing 4 comments, you could simply have written *`AsQueryable()` is useful if you want to expose a small cache like it was the real DB, in a way that you can switch them on the fly*... To which I would have replied, *yes, right, seen once in 5 years I've seen AsQueryable()... The other times it was `somequeryable.Where(somedelegatethatisntanexpression).AsQueryable()`*

Comment: thank you so much for this, 5 years later and it has just saved my bacon!!